# Issue with Ruby Bubble Sort

Tags: ruby

I have to make a bubble sort in ruby for a project, and I'm having trouble. I translated the pseudocode on wikipedia to ruby, and it's not working as expected. I'm not quite sure what's wrong.

```
swapped = false

def bubble_sort(list,swapped)
    length = list.length
    i = 1
    until !swapped do
        swapped = false
        list.each do |i|
            if list[i-1] > list[i]
                list[i-1], list[i] = list[i], list[i-1]
                swapped = true
            end
        end
    end
    return list
end

puts bubble_sort([1,3,7,4,6,9,10,5,8,2], swapped)
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: It's printing the original array passed in.

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all? I don't remember how a bubble sort is supposed to work, but the error you've made would become pretty apparent with even minimal efforts at debugging. I'll give you a hint, I would investigate the list.each block. That and you are missing the recursive part of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is here:

```
until !swapped do
```

since `swapped` is false the loop is not executed even once.

Apart from that:

```
list.each do |i|
    if list[i-1] > list[i]
        list[i-1], list[i] = list[i], list[i-1]
        swapped = true
    end
end
```

`i` is not an index, but the value, hence `list[i-1]` for third element will evaluate to `list[6]` (third element is 7). Instead you need to use index:

```
list.each_index do |i|
    if list[i-1] > list[i]
        list[i-1], list[i] = list[i], list[i-1]
        swapped = true
    end
end
```

Another problem is that `list[-1]` is a valid syntax and will return the last element of an array. You need to skip this element. Your `swapped` logic also is incorrect here, you set it to true as soon as you swap first elements, which changed `until` condition to false and breaks the loop, you should rather set it the other way around.

```
def bubble_sort(list)
  swapped = true
  while swapped do
    swapped = false
    list.each_index do |i|
      next if i == 0
      if list[i-1] > list[i]
        list[i-1], list[i] = list[i], list[i-1]
        swapped = true
      end
    end
  end
  list
end
```

Few more notes, you don't need the return statement, ruby method returns the value of the last executed line. Passing `swapped` as a param is completely obsolete.